# How to substitute string in variable from a specific character to the end in Windows cmd.exe?

Tags: windows, batch-file

**Prelude**

I know (e.g. from https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html) one can substitute a variable from the beginning to a character (here a `_`) by:

```
set var=foo_bar_baz
echo %var:*_=%
rem results in: bar_baz
```

**Question**

How can I substitute the `var`iable from the first `_` character to the end? So I obtain

```
rem results in: foo
```

??

I am running cmd.exe on Windows 7.

Comment: `set var=%var:_=&rem %`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tinkering with `for`, I solved it using

```
for /f "tokens=1 delims=_" %t in ("%var%") do set var=%t
```